# How secure is DRb with $SAFE = 1?

Tags: ruby, security, drb

I'm writing a program that will have decentralized nodes that connect to each other. Any node can (and should) connect to any other node, so every connection is considered to be untrusted. I've been considering using DRb with $SAFE set to 1, but I can't find any resources detailing exactly how secure it is.

Would it be safe to allow arbitrary connections with vanilla DRb? And if not, is there some way I can configure it to be so?